# Python3 compare 2 list with dictionary elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to filter out the same dictionary elements from two different list, sample as below:

```
a = [{'name':'Cheng','sex':'man','age':18},{'name':'Huang','sex':'man','age':19},{'name':'pan','sex':'woman','age':23},{'name':'Ying','sex':'woman','age':21}...]

b = [{'name':'Cheng','sex':'man','age':19},{'name':'pan','sex':'woman','age':23},{'name':'Huang','sex':'woman','age':20},{'name':'Ying','sex':'man','age':23}...]
```

List a and b has many dictionary elements.

I seek an efficient way to compare the different values with the same key in dictionary elements, the expected results should be like below:

```
[{'name':'pan','sex':'woman','age':23}...]
```

The same dictionary elements will be showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over one of the lists and check if an element of the first list is in the second list

```
print([item for item in a if item in b])
```

The output will be

```
[{'name': 'pan', 'sex': 'woman', 'age': 23}]
```